# How to comment multiple lines at once?

Tags: vim, vi, macro, block-comment

How can I select a bunch of text and comment it all out?

Currently I go to the first line, go to insert mode then type `#` <kbd>left-arrow</kbd><kbd>down-arrow</kbd> and then I repeat that sequence, perhaps saving a few keystrokes by using the `.` repeat feature to do each line.

Is there anyway I could (for instance) select either multiple lines in visual mode or by using a range of lines and an ex ('colon') command and for that range comment out all the lines with a `#` to make them a "block comment".

The ability to quickly 'de-comment' (remove the `#`'s) for a block comment would also be nice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462794/indent-or-comment-several-text-lines-with-vi

Comment: sed '/START/i \<<"COMMENT" \ /END/a\COMMENT\n' - you only change two lines. And to see what you commented add cat to the beginning.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

### Ranges:

You can do it with the following commands:

for commenting:

```
:66,70s/^/#
```

for uncommenting:

```
:66,70s/^#/
```

Obviously, here we're commenting lines from 66 to 70 (inclusive).

Comment: Are you sure you don't need insert an 's' after the range?

Comment: Maybe on your vim version but I'm sure of it, "s" stands from "substitution" /^  begining of the line by /# (hash). No mistery here.

Comment: if you want to comment `//` instead of `#` need to escape them with \. `:66,70s/^/\/\/`

Comment: one can refer [this link](https://www.ostechnix.com/comment-multiple-lines-vim-editor/) multiple methods are mentioned here by author for comment

Answer (score 247):

### Visual Block Mode

- First, move the cursor to the first char of the first line in block code you want to comment, then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>.

  Then vim will go into `VISUAL BLOCK` mode.
- Use `j` to move the cursor down until you reach the last line of your code block. Then type: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>
- Now vim goes to `INSERT` mode and the cursor is at the first char of the first line. Finally, type `#` then <kbd>ESC</kbd> and the code block is now commented.

**Note** that at first sight, the editing does not seem to differ from changing a single line. The changes will only be applied to the whole block **after** hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

To uncomment, do the same things but instead of type <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>, you just type <kbd>x</kbd> to remove all `#` after highlight them in `VISUAL BLOCK` mode.

Comment: Or even use `/` to jump to the endpoint, or `%` if the endpoint is a matching `}` (or `{` if jumping backwards).  I like the visual modes so much more than specifying ranges...

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. +1 for visual mode, -1 because `Shift I` opens an INSERT only on the first line of the selection. Could just be an OSX issue though, as it's VERY common with this OS that is completely inconsistent with Unix.

Comment: @MattClark: You tried it, didn't you? That how it suppose to work. After editing the first line, press `ESC` to quit insert mode, everything was applied to the rest of selected line.

Comment: Works with MacVim. Important to note that it only works with VISUAL BLOCK, not VISUAL or VISUAL LINE mode.

Comment: @atamanroman: Yes, that's how the title is!

Comment: @cuonglm that information was for those it does not seem to work for. Your answer ist correct. I just wanted to add that it does indeed only work with VISUAL BLOCK.

Comment: @atamanroman: I don't get your point. The title is stated that is's *visual block* mode.

Comment: read the comment from @MattClark: "+1 for _visual_ mode" and then he states it does not work on his machine (OSX). I tried it on OSX with macvim and it works, but you've got to use _visual block_, not _visual_ (nor _visual line_).

Comment: @cuonglm helped in VISUAL BLOCK mode ,thanks

Comment: On OSX with VISUAL LINE, I just have to press `ESC` two times to propagate to every selected line.

Comment: I tried this serveral times and it did not work for me. Until i realized, that I used shift + v and not ctrl + v. Thx @atamanroman

Comment: You can also use `Ctrl + v` and then jump down to the line number you want to include, e.g.: `50G` to jump to line 50.  Then `Shift + I` etc.

Answer (score 37):

### Substitute

For the sake of completeness here's another way:

1. Enter visual mode by pressing `v`
2. select the lines you like to comment (`up`/`down` arrow or `j`/`k`)
3. enter `:s/^/# /` which translates to: in selection (`:`) replace beginning of line (`^`) with `# '

Comment: This was the only version that worked for me. The SHIFT+i, then #, then ESC never did.

Comment: pasting the `:` did not work, I had to type it. pasting the rest (in my case `s/^/#/`) did work then

Answer (score 12):

### Markers:

The following steps are done in command mode:

1. go to first line and set the marker with `mt`
2. go to the line till which you want range
3. issue the command `:'t,.s/^/#/`

## Explanation

- `m#`, where `#` denotes any letter, puts a marker at your current location. The location can later be referred to using `'#`, where `#` is the same letter as before. In our case we used the letter `t`
- The command `:'t,.s/^/#/` reads as follows:

  - `:` the prefix for complex commands
  - `'t,.` defines the range at which the following command should apply. In our case, it is from marker `'t` till current line `.`
  - `s/^/#/` is a substitution formula, replacing all beginning-of-line `^` with literal character `#`

Comment: +1 markers are a good option that I've just starting using.

Answer (score 5):

### Plugin

There is a [plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218), which offers an efficient way of commenting out based on the file system being used.

Also, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226390/how-to-use-nerd-commenter-for-vim-how-to-use-leader-key) discusses how to use the `NERD commenter` for `vim`. Few more basic instructions on how to use the plugin are discussed [here](http://spf13.com/post/vim-plugins-nerd-commenter).

Answer (score 1):

Use either NERDCommenter as mentioned, but if that's not available to me I use the visual modes. I go into Visual Line mode, make my selection, often its blocks of whitespace, so I go <kbd>V{</kbd> then change to Visual Block mode with <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> and then insert the comment symbol at the start of the lines with <kbd>I</kbd>, so to comment out a block of text, I'd do

```
V{<C-Q>I#<Esc>
```